# Magento's log cleaning shell script cleans `report_event` and `report_viewed_product_index`?

Tags: ee-1.13, log, maintenance

Magento comes with a log-cleaning process as a Magento shell script located at `shell/log.php`, which is also used in the log maintenance configurable in the admin.

I traced the code to `Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Log` for the piece responsible for cleaning when `php -f log.php clean --days xxx` is executed. I'm running it manually, and I'm seeing `report_event` and `report_viewed_product_index` being cleaned as well, even though I don't see any reference to them in the code. Any ideas?

**Update**

I was able to `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, which shows me everything I need to know.

`report_viewed_product_index`:

```
CREATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_index` (
  `index_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Index Id',
  `visitor_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Visitor Id',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Id',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `added_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Added At',
  PRIMARY KEY (`index_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_VISITOR_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`visitor_id`,`product_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_CUSTOMER_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`customer_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `IDX_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_ADDED_AT` (`added_at`),
  KEY `IDX_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_REPORT_VIEWED_PRD_IDX_CSTR_ID_CSTR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_REPORT_VIEWED_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11096 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Reports Viewed Product Index Table'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the `report_viewed_product_index` table you'll notice that it has a couple of relevant indexes, most notably:

- `UNQ_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_VISITOR_ID_PRODUCT_ID`, and
- `UNQ_REPORT_VIEWED_PRODUCT_INDEX_CUSTOMER_ID_PRODUCT_ID`

As the visitor & customer IDs are being truncated by the

- `_cleanVisitors()`, and
- `_cleanCustomers()`

methods (of `app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Log.php`) respectively, it means that any record indexing it as a primary key will be dropped as well, and due to the nature of this particular *[BTREE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html)* index it means that by truncating one table, (i.e `log/visitor`) it would essentially do the same to this table.

[image: phpMyAdmin preview of BTREE index structure]

**P.S:** This explanation holds true for the other table (`report_event`) as well.

Comment: Those `UNQ_...` are just unique index names, aren't they? How do you know by reading just the keynames that `log/visitor` and `log/customer` record deletions cascade? I did post the `CONSTRAINT`s which does show such condition.

Comment: (Separately) The `CONSTRAINT`s I posted tells us that deleting records in `customer_entity` and `catalog_product_entity` with designated keys also deletes corresponding records in `report_viewed_product_index`. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

See the observer plugged on log_log_clean_after : eventClean

The code is pretty self explanatory whereas why your reports are being cleaned :)

```
$event = Mage::getModel('reports/event');
$event->clean();
Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_compared')->clean();
Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_viewed')->clean();
```

I know it is too years late but I hope it'll help future viewers.